# Is this differential equation solvable in MATLAB?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

\begin{align}
    r'' - r θ'^2 &= g \sinθ - (M/m)(g - y'')
\\    
    r' + Rθ' + y' &= 0
  \\  
    rθ'' + 2r'θ' + g \cosθ &= 0
\end{align}

Sorry may I know how I can solve this with ode45? I am attempting to convert all three equations into 1st Order Coupled equations, but I can't seem to get the second equation into the correct substitution. Is it possible? Or do I have to use another ODE solver (which?)

Edit: I attempted rob's solution, and have gotten the following code

Taking M=3m, g=9.81, R=4

```
function dydt = odefun(t,y)
dydt = zeros(9,1)
dydt(1) = y(7)
dydt(2) = y(8)
dydt(3) = y(9)
dydt(4) = sqrt((y(8)-9.81*sin(y(4))-3*9.81+3*y(9))/(2*y(1)))
dydt(5) = -(9.81*cos(y(4))+y(5)*y(7))/(2*y(1))
dydt(6) = -y(2)-y(1)*4
end
```

but received the following error message

```
Not enough input arguments.
Error in <filename> (line 3)
dydt(1) = y(7)
```

It seems matlab does not accept the code if I do not define (θ'')' = ___. Sorry if this is a dumb misunderstanding, I am still trying to figure out how MATLAB works (any resources to recommend?)

I have also attempted

```
function dydt = odefun(t,y)
dydt = zeros(9,1)
dydt(1) = y(7)
dydt(2) = y(8)
dydt(3) = y(9)
dydt(4) = sqrt((y(8)-9.81*sin(y(4))-3*9.81+3*y(9))/(2*y(1)))
dydt(5) = -(9.81*cos(y(4))+y(5)*y(7))/(2*y(1))
dydt(6) = -y(2)-y(1)*4 % radius here!
dydt(4) = y(1) % are these 3 more lines correct logically, they seem to 
dydt(5) = y(2) % let matlab run, but for now I am just getting constants
dydt(6) = y(3) % for all solutions
end
```

is this the right code?

Comment: Did you mean in your edit (v3) to insert a new constant $R$ or the variable $r$?

Comment: I have updated the question :)

Comment: I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's certainly possible to turn these three second-order differential equations into six first-order ones. Your differentiation function will therefore have six inputs --- three coordinates and their three first derivatives --- and six outputs. (I think Matlab uses a vector of length six.)
The first three are trivial: the velocities your function spits out should be the velocities you put in:

\begin{align}
\frac d{dt} r &= r' \tag1\\
\frac d{dt} \theta &= \theta' \tag2\\
\frac d{dt} y &= y' \tag3
\end{align}

The other three derivatives you have to isolate from your equations of motion. The simplest route seems to want two auxiliary definitions.  From your first equation,

$$
\Delta = r'' - \frac Mm y'' = r\theta'^2 + g\left(\sin\theta - \frac Mm \right).
$$

From (the derivative of) your second,

$$
\Sigma = r'' + y'' = -\frac d{dt}(r\theta') = - r'\theta' - r\theta''.
$$

(If I'm misreading your second equation and you mean a constant $R$ rather than the dynamical $r$, that's an easy substitution here, with $R' = 0$; note also $\theta''$ below.)
Then the derivatives of the velocities that you input are

\begin{align}
\frac d{dt} r' &= \frac{M\Sigma + m\Delta}{M+m} \tag4 \\
\frac d{dt} \theta' &= \frac{-2 r'\theta'- g\cos\theta}r \tag5 \\
\frac d{dt} y' &= \frac{M\Sigma - m\Delta}{2M} \tag6 \\
\end{align}

[player100](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/354664/player100) points out in a comment that this system of equations actually isn't sensitive to a constant offset in $y$: the system is first-order in $y'$ rather than second-order in $y$.  However, if $y$ is what *interests* you, then it's probably better to include it in your integrator than to leave it out.  Integrating algorithms which make decisions about dynamically changing step sizes do so based on the error terms in the data that they have to look at.

You ask in a comment about when, in general, we can determine whether a system of equations is under/overdetermined; I think that's an interesting question, but too broad for this answer.

Note that [a previous version of this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/2908836/2) put the "trivial" derivatives in the wrong place. Sorry about that --- it's been a long time since I `ode45`'d anything, and I'm rusty.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Sorry. Just to clarify, we are not using ode45 (Runge Kutta) anymore right, but are instead using an integrating solver? Because if we want to use ode45, we need to have a definition for (θ'')' = ___, in order for ode45 (Runge Kutta) to solve it?

Comment: Sorry for terminology --- I think of Runge-Kutta as an integrating method, but perhaps there's a better technical name for it. You do not need any expression for the derivative of $\theta''$ because there are no third derivatives in your equations of motion --- but if you did need one, it would be the trivial $\frac d{dt}\theta'' = \theta'''$.

Comment: oh, I think I got the misunderstanding that every new "variable" we define (in this case θ'') needs to have another equation telling ode45 what its derivative is [(θ'')' = ___]... from the documentation for ode45. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: That's not correct. Given these six equations, your integrator has enough information to tell you $r,\theta,y$ and their derivatives $r',\theta', y'$ as functions of time.

Comment: thanks! just a little curious, how can we tell when we have enough information/equations to determine the solutions? I understand the idea for linear equations, but for differential equations I am abit lost. Searching only gives me results for specific theorems and conditions, but not for a general system of ODEs like this. Is there a good explanation, or any good resources on solvability you recommend?

Comment: You can at least eliminate one variable, for example $y$ from the second equation.

Comment: hi, I have edited the ODE to include a R (length) term in front of the theta' to satisfy dimensional analysis (I removed it when asking for simplicity, thinking it was unimportant).. I have edited the question to include the matlab code I inputted. However, I see why I don't need an expression for theta'' mathematically, but how do I get matlab to accept it? thanks.

Comment: I don't think this system of DE can be implemented numerically in MATLAB. It should be in the form of $\frac{dx}{dt}= f(x,t)$. So f cannot have second derivatives in it.

Comment: @ahmetselcuk I don't think that's correct. It's been a long time since I did numerical integration specifically in Matlab, but I *know* it was a system with second derivatives. The trick is that the second derivatives of the positions are the first derivatives of the velocities, so your input vector has two entries for each coordinate.

Comment: @rob It could be a system of second derivatives. But I don't think there was term like $f(x_1'',x_2'',..)$ on the right side. If there were then we would have to have third derivatives.  It should  have a form like $\frac{dx}{dt}=f(x,t)$.

Comment: @ahmetselcuk I would agree with you if there were a circular dependence on the second derivatives, but there isn't. $\theta''$ can be written only in terms of $r,\theta,r',\theta'$. The intermediate $\Sigma$ depends on $\theta''$, but we've already computed $\theta''$ so that's not a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Take $r-y = u$ and $r+y = v$ then

\begin{align}
 u''+\frac{(v+u)\theta'^2}{2} &= g \sin\theta -g  
\\ v'+ \theta' &= 0 
\\ \frac{(v+u)}{2} \theta''+ \frac{(v'+u')}{2}+g \cos\theta &= 0
\end{align}

From the second equation, $ \theta = c-v$ for some constant $c$. Then take $x_1 =u, x_2=v, x_3= u', x_4=v' $ so for numerical solution

\begin{align}
   \frac{dx_1}{dt} &= x_3 \\
   \frac{dx_2}{dt} &= x_4 \\
   \frac{dx_3}{dt} &= -\frac{(x_1+x_2)x_4^2}{2}+g\sin(c-x_2)-g \\
   \frac{dx_4}{dt} &= \frac{x_3+x_4}{x_1+x_2}+\frac{2g\cos(c-x_2)}{x_1+x_2} 
\end{align}

For initial conditions you need only five of them: four for differential equations and one for determining $c$. Also there seems to be a potential annoyance around $x_1=-x_2$, i.e. $r=0$.